# "the right way" vs. "in the right way"

Tags: word-usage

In my other post (["that" vs. "if" in the context of indirect question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/240200/109190)) I said

> Actually I am not sure if I dealt with that problem **in** the right way.

where I put an extra "**in**".

Another expression is without the extra "**in**", and [seems more common](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22the%20right%20way%22).

> Actually I am not sure if I dealt with that problem the right way.

The question is whether both are idiomatic. Any ideas?

---

The following part should be treated as archived, corresponding the existing discussion.

In my other [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344928/714660) I said

> I am not sure if I did it **in** the right way.

where I put an extra "**in**".

I found [lots of people also use the expression](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22in%20the%20right%20way%22).

Another expression is without the extra "**in**", and [seems more common](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22the%20right%20way%22).

> I am not sure if I did it the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is quite the stylistic one.
 
 Indeed, the usage of 'in' may be considered as weird ([link](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/in-a-right-way-in-the-right-way.2838597/)). The thing is, 'do in' means 'do in a certain location.' Hence, I have a question: what do you mean when say 'do in a/the right way'? No doubt, you will be understood...but it is not preferred (my personal experience says so, but you can resist if you wish).

On the other hand,`I am not sure if I did it the right way` implies *how* you acted. You did it (*how?*) the right way. And, yes, it is idiomatic, plus lexically and grammatically correct. As proof, Forbes actively [uses](https://www.forbes.com/sites/forbestechcouncil/2018/02/21/doing-the-right-thing-and-doing-it-the-right-way/#124eaa285b22) it.

EDIT: Despite a verb you use (do, deal, etc.) the situation is equivalent: deal the problem (*how?*) the right way (explanation above), and it is an idiomatic expression ([example](https://www.betterhelp.com/advice/rejection/how-to-deal-with-rejection-the-right-way/) of usage). 
 
Again, if taken under scrutiny, the preposition "in" is misused.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I guess my bad example mislead you. I've updated my question just now, would you please take a loot at that?